# How to authenticate LDAP connection on Git (gogs)?

Tags: git, bash, server, ldap, gogs

I'm trying to set up a Git server on my company virtual server using http://gogs.io git service. They have the set-up for LDAP connection but there are no way to test the authentication.  Or is that any command that I could use in the git bash that could help to connect with the AD server?

Sorry I'm not really technical or familiar with their set-up.

On my LDAP Config I put these:

```
Host : *my company host server*
Port : 389
UserDN : CN=%s,OU=Head Office,OU=Users,OU=ID,OU=APAC,DC=nead,DC=tpnet
User filter : (&(objectcategory=person)(samaccountname=*)(mail=*))
Email attribute : mail
```

Should I use simple authentication or Bind DN authentication? what's the difference between them?

Comment: This is not a SO question IMHO. Please consider migrating this to [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: I asked ths question in serverfault but they put it on hold. I don't know what to do now. w(-_-")w @mona_sax

Comment: @mona_sax: since this is a programmer tool, I think it is covered within the on-topic themes. However, I doubt there is enough information here to help - Venessa, can we see your config file etc?

Comment: @halfer I put the config file above, please could you take a look at it? thank you so much

Comment: I'm not familiar with this tool, so I can't help personally. Good question though, upvoted. Is there any information about LDAP in the docs?

Comment: If you feel you have genuinely exhausted all possible avenues, I can put a bounty on this question, if you are willing to stick around to take advantage of any answers received. Would that help?

Comment: @halfer I finally found the solution hahaha turns out my mistake is on the user filter value. I use this and it works  '(&(sAMAccountName=%s))' but thank you for the offer :)

Comment: @Venessa, It's great you solved the issue. Can you please post an answer to help future users comming to this post, including answer to the question of diff between simple authentication and Bind DN authentication. I also have an issue, I asked a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607973/how-to-import-data-from-ldap-to-gogs).  have a look if you can answer.