# How to import data from LDAP to gogs

Tags: ldap, gogs

I was trying to integrate LDAP server to our [gogs](https://gogs.io/). I followed instructions from [here](https://discuss.gogs.io/t/how-to-configure-ldap-in-gogs/767/3) and [here](https://gogs.io/docs/features/authentication).
But what next? How to import data from LDAP to gogs? I am unable to find anyway of importing data. 
And without importing data, the integration of no use. I have developed a helpdesk system, there I did same in PHP, but there, after integration, I got an option to test and import data from LDAP. 
But how to do that in Gogs? I really have no idea. 
Any help on How to import data from LDAP into GOGS?